# Solving for a set of points from projections

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse-problems

Consider a set of $N$ points in $n$-dimensional space, i.e.
\begin{align*}
   S = \{x_1, \dots, x_N\} \subset \mathbb R^n.
\end{align*}
Let $v \in \mathbb R^n$ and consider the image set (not counting multiplicities (!))
  $$ P_v S := \{y \; | \;\exists x \in S \text{ such that } \langle v , x \rangle = y \} $$
which can be seen as a projection of the set $S=\{x_1, \dots, x_N\}$.

Consider the problem of reconstructing the set $S$ from projections $P_v S$ where $v \in V \subset \mathbb R^n$.

My question is: Under which conditions on the family of vectors $V$ we can uniquely reconstruct the set $S=\{x_1, \dots, x_N\}$? Clearly it is necessary that $V$ contains a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. But this is not sufficient as one easily sees in simple examples (e.g. $n=2$, $N=3$). Loosely speaking, the set $V$ has to be large enough.

Comment: Just to make clear, the set $P_v(S)$ is the set of projections on $v$ (roughly), and not on the plane orthogonal to $v$, right?

Comment: I'll answer with an example: Let $n=2$ and consider $S = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1.3,2), (1,0) \}$ and let us consider one vector $v = (1,1)$. Then $P_v S = \{0, \; 1, \; 3.3\}$ :-).

Answer (score 2):

$n+1$ generic vectors are enough; on the other hand, $n$ never suffice.

Take the canonical basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $E_i = P_{e_i}S$. The set $S$ lies in $E = E_1\times E_2\times\cdots\times E_n$, which is a finite set.

No set of $n$ vectors can get you further than this "discrete cube", so you can never tell the difference between -say- $S=E$ and $S = E\setminus \{p\}$ (so long as $E$ has at least 4 points); if the $n$ vectors are not linearly independent, you don't even get any discrete set, but you get a union of affine subspaces of positive dimension, so that's hopeless.

We are looking for a vector $v$ such that no (affine) hyperplane orthogonal to $v$ contains two points in $E$. The condition that a (linear) hyperplane doesn't contain a fixed linear subspace is dense and open, hence so is the condition that it doesn't contain a finite set of linear subspaces. Since $E$ is finite, so is the set of lines going through pairs of points of $E$. Therefore, any generic $v$ separates points in $E$, and $P_v$ is guaranteed to be injective on $S$; so we are able to decide which points of $E$ are actually in $S$.

On the "practical" level, I think that choosing coordinates of $v$ so that they give a set of trascendece $n$ over the subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $E_1\cup\dots\cup E_n$ is abundantly sufficient. (*e.g.* if all coordinates of points in $E$ are rational, and $n=2$, taking $\pi$ and $e^\pi$ should be sufficient).

Comment: Also, notice that the same argument also applies when $S$ is countable, rather than finite.